# Using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to prove that $\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{x-1}{x+1}=3$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow -2} \frac{x-1}{x+1}=3.
$$

I am stuck on this question please help me with it! I really do not know how to start effectively. I am new to this very precise, abstract form of thinking.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: @5xum I am not sure...

Comment: Not good enough. If you put zero effort into your question, then expect zero effort put into the answers.

Comment: Try copying the worked example on this wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28%CE%B5,_%CE%B4%29-definition_of_limit. You should be able to reach $|x+2| < \frac{ |x+1|}{2} \varepsilon$.

Comment: @5xum You should talk some sense into user103828. In general, yes, high-quality answers should not be provided for low-quality questions, but sometimes answers are written not just for the OP in mind. And certainly downvoting a very high-quality post simply because the person doesn't deem the original question worthy of attention is an idiotic reason.

Comment: @crash Actually, downvoting answes like yours is perfectly valid. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16412/answers-to-basic-questions-which-are-too-detailed this thread.

Comment: @5xum Downvoting anything is "valid," but whether or not it is appropriate is really the question--I don't think downvoting my answer here is appropriate, for the OP is just a member as of today, and s/he has received plenty of feedback concerning what is considered a high- versus low-quality post. I think my answer does more good than harm here.

Comment: @crash In this particular case, I agree. But I also think that there are reasons to both vote your answer up and down. In my opinion, they more or less cancel out (hence, no vote from me). It is perfectly reasonable that someone estimates the downsides outweigh the upsides. Such a person *should* downvote a question, and it is appropriate to do so. You cannot say that every downvote you disagree with is inappropriate.

Comment: @5xum I agree with everything you said if I understood it all correctly. I think it's hard to make a case that my answer has more downsides than upsides here, but I have given answers in the past that could certainly garner a downvote or two (and have) by their very nature...whether a terse hint or overly drawn out answer, etc. So I definitely agree with your last line. I was just rather miffed in this particular instance when the person who downvoted my answer was the same person who posted an incorrect answer. Maybe that will make more sense.

Comment: @crash *I think it's hard to make a case that my answer has more downsides than upsides here*. I don't thing it's that hard. It's pretty much oppinion based. Don't concern yourself about downvotes too much. Majority voting will make sure that any good answer you make will have a positive net sum.

Answer (score 7):

I am only going to answer this because I know how tricky these problems are for beginners (took me a long time to understand how to do them as well--I understand that *even* beginning effectively can be rather difficult). Thus, in the future, at least show *some* work or ideas on how you thought about going about it. Otherwise, you cannot count on getting good answers. That being said consider the following: (1) In the first part, I'll go through the process of guessing a value for $\delta$ [this is really an art form], and (2) I'll show you that this $\delta$ does, indeed, work.

**Part 1 (Guessing a value for $\delta$):** Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. We have to find a number $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}-3\right|=\left|\frac{x-1-3x-3}{x+1}\right|=\left|\frac{-2x-4}{x+1}\right|=\left|\frac{-2(x+2)}{x+1}\right|=\frac{2}{|x+1|}\cdot|x+2|<\epsilon
$$
whenever $0<|x+2|<\delta$. We find a positive constant $C$ such that 
$$
\frac{2}{|x+1|}<C\Rightarrow \frac{2}{|x+1|}\cdot|x+2| < C|x+2|,
$$
and we can make $C|x+2|<\epsilon$ by taking $|x+2|<\frac{\epsilon}{C}=\delta$. We restrict $x$ (**note:** this is where part of the "art form" comes into play) to lie in the interval $|x+2|<\frac{1}{2}$, whereby we note that
$$
|x+2|<\frac{1}{2}\Longleftrightarrow -\frac{3}{2}<x+1<-\frac{1}{2}\Longleftrightarrow -\frac{2}{3}>\frac{1}{x+1}>-2\Longleftrightarrow -\frac{4}{3}>\frac{2}{x+1}>-4.
$$
Thus, certainly
$$
\frac{2}{x+1}>-4 \Longrightarrow 4>\frac{2}{|x+1|}>-4. 
$$
So $C=4$ is suitable. Thus, we should choose $\delta=\min\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{4}\}$. Now we need to check if this $\delta$ really works.

**Part 2 (Showing that $\delta$ works):** Given $\epsilon>0$, we let $\delta=\min\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{4}\}$. If $0<|x+2|<\delta$, then $\frac{2}{|x+1|}<4$, as we saw above in Part 1. Also, $|x+2|<4\epsilon$, so
$$
\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}-3\right|=\frac{2}{|x+1|}\cdot|x+2|<4\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{4}=\epsilon.
$$

This shows that
$$
\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{x-1}{x+1}=3.\quad\blacksquare
$$

Comment: I down-voted because, in the comments, it was exactly discussed that no attempt is "not good enough."

Comment: @user103828 (1) The comment was in response to OP's comment, where 5xum was not satisfied with the response, hence "not good enough", and (2) What an idiotic reason to downvote...you have only 25 downvotes in your history and you chose my high-quality answer to downvote? That's completely illogical. There's even a badge awarded to people who provide very high-quality answers to very low-quality questions.

Comment: I can't understand why does user103828 downvote here only because something was discussed in the comments below the question. As if the comments were the rule for all. This answer is correct, is well detailed and explanatory, and even though I'd rather answer by hints and not by complete answers, **in this case** I think it is completely justified to give a full answer *in order to help the obviously beginner OP to understand* . I'm still surprised the OP hasn't yet upvoted this answer and even hasn't chosen it. +1

Comment: @Timbuc **Thank you**. I completely agree. In case the downvoter cares to see another case of a long, detailed answer provided with not just the OP in mind, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184541/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-weak-and-strong-induction/1184785#1184785) very long answer about induction. I oftentimes recommend friends to check out MSE even though they may not have an account. Sometimes high-quality answers can help *everyone* out, even if the OP posts what is deemed a "garbage question" according to the help center.

Comment: I delayed my up vote due to the self-acclaimed high quality answer. In the end one should vote on posts, not on posters or attitudes. This is something the community doesn't realise.

Comment: @GitGud I agree, and I don't really care about upvotes, but I do care about downvotes on an answer that I took a good amount of time to write up and that was accurate. The user who downvoted actually posted an incorrect answer and then subsequently deleted it. I only made my "self-acclaimed high quality answer" comment due to the fact that the user downvoted it, and I wanted to draw attention to this illogical downvote. Don't know if that clears things up, but obviously I was annoyed about what I thought was a good answer being senselessly downvoted.

Comment: @crash: I see your answers every now and then and you clearly put a lot of effort into writing each one. Just read on your profile how you're waiting for your account to be deleted. I hope you still continue helping others with math. Also, congratulations on getting $\lfloor1000\sqrt2\rfloor$ profile views!

Comment: @Regret Thanks a lot for that. Really appreciate it. Users like you make MSE worth staying around--my account was actually scheduled to be deleted in a few hours and I was just helping out here and there before I let it go through with deletion, but your comment...well, it's convinced me to stay around. May seem odd I'd make such a decision based on one comment, but it's not just one comment--a few users (several with > 3000 rep) have mentioned that they would be sorry to see me leave, that I've contributed "a lot of valuable stuff in only a little time" (that was Meelo). SO, I'm going to

Comment: @Regret [cont’d] stick around now. :) Not *just* because of your comment, but your comment was the tipping point. My experience with my $\pi$-day question was **horrible**…I can easily see why new users leave quickly. I will likely pose a question on meta to address some of my concerns. Based on my readings in the past of some meta posts, several other > 5000 rep users have left MSE due to reasons similar to why I was going to leave. Anyway, thank you for your kind comment. I look forward to us bumping into each others’ answers/questions again soon. :)

Comment: @Regret I should also maybe add a portion of a moderator's (Jyrki) private message to me: "I realize that something about the site has recently frustrated you. That happens to many of us, and takes some time to get used to." I think Jyrki is a great moderator, but I've been pretty annoyed by some of the other ones. Guess that's part of the process though. Well, thanks again for your support--your comment really did convince me to stay around. :)

Comment: @Regret Just wanted to drop you a line on an old inactive post so as not to disturb anything. Our little back-and-forth comments on that [earlier induction question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209845/is-induction-valid-when-starting-at-a-negative-number-as-a-base-case) inspired me to write up a more or less full response/answer. I even used the example you provided in your first comment that I saw you have since deleted. If you do check out my answer, please let me know if you have any issues with it. I don't think we were disagreeing at all in our earlier comments. :)

Comment: @crash: I don't see any issues with your answer, I like it.  Thanks for letting me know you posted it. Also, you have a nice new bio! Disguising the current user link... :)

Comment: @Regret hehe shhhh!!! Gotta keep it under wraps. It's already fooled a number of people so far. :D