# How does $( 1 - (1- \frac{1}{2^{2^k}}))$ become $(1+ \frac{1}{2^{2^k}})$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How does $\left( 1 - \left(1- \frac{1}{2^{2^k}}\right)\right)$ become $\left(1+ \frac{1}{2^{2^k}}\right)$?

I distributed the former but got negative $-\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}$. So it does not match the latter.

I'm basing the math from this website: http://zimmer.csufresno.edu/~larryc/proofs/proofs.mathinduction.html
Please observe the math 2nd part of inductive step for the 2nd example(a recurrence formula)

Comment: If you want $2^{2^k}$, type 2^{2^k} in dollar signs, and if you want $(2^2)^k$, type (2^2)^k in dollar signs. The problem is not the fraction, but the fact that the expression is ambiguous if you don't group the exponents.

Comment: @ColdNumber +1 for you. Followed your advice.

Comment: There is an issue, mathematically, with your question, regardless of the potential for ambiguity. The two things aren't equal. At all.

Comment: Glad it worked :). Now, about your question, I don't understand what you mean by "become". Are  you asking whether the expressions are equal?

Comment: Based on your [most recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361057/what-are-valid-base-case-values-for-proofs-by-mathematical-induction) concerning induction, it seems like you are struggling to master the concept and/or mechanics of proofs by induction. You may find [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139579/why-is-mathematical-induction-a-valid-proof-technique) and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196303/fake-induction-proofs) to be of use while trying to better understand this proof technique.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:  Looking at the link you provided, you missed a couple of divisions.

$$\left(1-\left(1-\frac 1{2^{2^k}}\right)\Big/2\right) = \left( 1+ \frac 1 {2^{2^k}}\right)\Big/2$$

---

The line in question, when MathJaxed up a bit, is:
$$\begin{align}a_{k+1} & = \left(2 \left(1 - \frac 1{2^{2^k}}\right)\frac 12 \right)\; \left(1 - \left(1 - \frac 1{2^{2^k}}\right)\frac 1 2\right) \\ & = \left(1 - \frac 1 {2^{2^k}}\right)\;\left(1 + \frac 1{2^{2^k}}\right)\frac 12
\\ & = \color{blue}{\left(1 - \left(\frac 1 {2^{2^{k}}}\right)^2\right)\frac 12}
\\ & = \color{blue}{\left(1 - \frac 1 {2^{2\times 2^{k}}}\right)\frac 12}
\\ & = \left(1 - \frac 1 {2^{2^{k+1}}}\right)\frac 12\end{align}$$

EDIT: Added additional steps.

Comment: I copied the numbers correctly from the solution...unless the instructor made a typo for the solution.

Comment: May you explain the last two parts? You multiplied the fraction by itself and got the result. But I cannot comprehend why you got the result you did.

Comment: @Nicholas, I have added two additional steps.  Does this help?

Comment: +1 Oh right! Now I understand. $2^k^2$ is the same as much 2 * 2^k.

Answer (score 2):

You have $a_{k+1}=2a_k(1-a_k)$, with $a_k=\frac 12 \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}\right).$ You were missing the $\frac 12$, as Graham Kemp notes.

The inductive step should read: 
\begin{align} a_{k+1}=2a_k(1-a_k)&=2\frac 12 \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}\right)\left(1-\frac 12 \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}\right)\right)\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}\right)\left(1-\frac 12 +\frac 12\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}\right)\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}\right)\left(1 +\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}\right)\frac 12\\
&= \frac 12 \left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}\right)^2    \right)\\
&= \frac 12 \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^{k+1}}}    \right)
\end{align}

Comment: May you explain the last two parts? You multiplied the fraction by itself and got the result. But I cannot comprehend why you got the result you did.

Comment: @Nicholas: The first of the last two parts follows from $(1-a)(1+a)=(1-a^2)$, where $a$ is your fraction. The second one: the denominator of the fraction squared is $2^{2^k}\cdot 2^{2^k}=2^{2^k+2^k}=2^{2\cdot 2^k}=2^{2^{k+1}}$. Were these the parts you were referring to?

Comment: oh okay. now I understand both parts. You broke it down that I understood it 100%!

Comment: Glad I could help :)