# Using Binomial Theorem to solve a question

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The question is this:

> "We assume that $a$,$b$ are positive numbers(they might not be integers)
>   but  $a+b$ and $a*b$ are integers, prove that for every $n$ $\in$$\mathbb{N}$ the numbers $a^n + b^n$ are integers.

Hint(Use Binominal Theorem).

I've tried to solve it but I couldn't. I could use some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the Binomial Theorem. Use induction.

Note that $a^n+b^n$ holds for $n=0,1$ from the conditions provided. Now asssume it is true for $n=m$, $n=m+1$. Then using [Newton's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) $$a^{m+2}+b^{m+2}=(a+b)(a^{m+1}+b^{m+1})-ab(a^m+b^m)$$
We find it holds for $m+2$ as well.

Thus, our proof is done.

**EDIT**

Upon second consideration, one can prove this using the Binomial Theorem by using strong induction. Assume that the proposition holds true for all $n<m$.

If $m$ is even, $$a^m+b^m=(a+b)^m-\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{m-2}{2}} \binom{m}{i} a^ib^i(a^{m-i}+b^{m-i})-\binom{m}{\frac{m}{2}}a^{\frac{m}{2}}b^{\frac{m}{2}} \in \mathbb{Z}$$ By the inductive hypothesis.
If $m$ is odd, $$a^m+b^m=(a+b)^m-\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{m-1}{2}} \binom{m}{i} a^ib^i(a^{m-i}+b^{m-i})\in \mathbb{Z}$$
From the inductive hypothesis. We are done.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer,But i have one more question about your answer, why did you subctract it by ab(a^m + b^m) ?

Comment: @Shadi Your welcome. :) I suggest you accept an answer to take this off the unanswered portion. You can do that by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: @Shadi To make $a^m+b^m$. Without it we have unnecessary terms. See the link I left in the answer.

Comment: It actually looks challenging to prove this *with* the Binomial theorem...

Comment: @YvesDaoust this question is made up for 2 parts, the first part is to write the biniominal thoerim equation and the other part is to solve this with a hint that this is the method that we should use,but seeing an answer like this made it look much easier... i couldn't solve it with binomial theorem after 1 and a half hour of trying and i'm supposed to solve it in 10mins

Comment: @YvesDaoust See my edit. :)

Comment: Yep, it seems that you need both the BT and induction. So the hint seems a little sadistic :)

Answer (score 0):

$$(a^n+b^n)(a+b)=a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}+ab(a^{n-1}+b^{n-1})$$

$$\iff a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}=(a^n+b^n)(a+b)-ab(a^{n-1}+b^{n-1})$$

Now use Strong Induction.

See : [Proving that $\frac{\phi^{400}+1}{\phi^{200}}$ is an integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936479/proving-that-frac-phi4001-phi200-is-an-integer/936481#936481)

Comment: It seems we posted the same answer, about $21$ seconds apart.

Comment: @S.C.B., Yours is without the derivation of the Proposition and without mentioning of Strong Induction?

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517440/whats-the-difference-between-simple-induction-and-strong-induction and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184541/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-weak-and-strong-induction

Comment: What do you mean? We don't need to derive it for the proposition, as it is provided in the condition. I mentioned induction.

Comment: We don't need strong induction for this, but I find that difference isn't very big.

Comment: @S.C.B.,  By proposition, I meant   $$a^{m+2}+b^{m+2}=(a+b)(a^{m+1}+b^{m+1})-ab(a^m+b^m)$$  Is it weak induction?