# z the root of $z+\frac{1}{z}=2\cos\frac{\pi}{2018} $ then the value of $z^{2018}+\frac{1}{z^{2018}}$ is..

Tags: trigonometry

$z \in\mathbb{C}^{*}$ is a root of the equation $z+\frac{1}{z}=2\cos\frac{\pi}{2018} $ then $z^{2018}+\frac{1}{z^{2018}}$ has the value...the right answer is -2.

Comment: whatever $a$ is, $z+\frac1z=a$ is a quadratic equation.

Comment: Rewrite $z$ as $e^{i\theta}$...

Comment: Does $\Bbb C^\ast$ denote the set of unit complex numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\theta:=\frac{\pi}{2018}$ so$$z^2-(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})z+1=0\implies z=e^{\pm i\theta}\\\implies z^{2018}+z^{-2018}=2\cos\pi=-2.$$

Comment: Hi!Thank you for your answer.I didn't learn at school about the fact with $e^{i..}$.Can I use Moivre formula or something else to solve this ? I got a quadratic $z^2-za+1=0$ where $a=2cos(\pi/2018)$ and I got the discriminant $2\sqrt{cos^2(a)-1}$

Comment: how to continue?

Comment: @DaniVaja All we're using here is $2\cos x=e^{ix}+e^{-ix}$, which follows from $e^{\pm ix}=\cos x\pm i\sin x$.

Comment: Thanks. I delete my comment.

Comment: Ok, I understood this but I didn;t understood why $z=e^{+-i*theta}$

Comment: I see that the equation it's a quadratic

Comment: @DaniVaja With factorisation $\prod_\pm(z-\exp\pm i\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

If  $z+\dfrac1z=2\cos t$

$z^2+\dfrac1{z^2}=\left(z+\dfrac1z\right)^2-2=\cdots=2\cos2t$

Similarly, $z^3+\dfrac1{z^3}=\left(z+\dfrac1z\right)^3-3\left(z+\dfrac1z\right)=\cdots=2\cos3t$

Like [Proving that $\frac{\phi^{400}+1}{\phi^{200}}$ is an integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936479/proving-that-frac-phi4001-phi200-is-an-integer/936481#936481)

using [strong induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184541/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-weak-and-strong-induction)

$$z^{n+1}+\dfrac1{z^{n+1}}=\left(z^n+\frac1{z^n}\right)\left(z+\frac1z\right)-\left(z^{n-1}+\frac1{z^{n-1}}\right) =2\cos nt\cdot2\cos t-2\cos(n-1)t$$

By [Werner Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html)

$$z^{n+1}+\dfrac1{z^{n+1}}=2[\cos(n-1)t+\cos(n+1)t]-2\cos(n-1)t$$

$$\implies z^{n+1}+\dfrac1{z^{n+1}}=2\cos(n+1)t$$