# Weak Induction implies Strong Induction Proof Inquiry

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification, first-order-logic

I am trying to improve my ability to *think formally* and *write public posts informally*. This requires a sort of "toggling" between one and the other. In the following question, I would like to confirm that I am correctly producing this conversion.

---

I read a post ([What exactly is the difference between weak and strong induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184541/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-weak-and-strong-induction)) about the distinctions (really, semantic equivalence) between **weak induction** and **strong induction**.

The accepted and heavily thumbed-up answer shows that weak induction implies strong induction and that strong induction implies weak induction.

The following definitions were provided for weak induction and strong induction:

**Weak Induction**:

"Let $S(n)$ denote a statement regarding an integer $n$, and let $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ be fixed. If

- (i) $S(k)$ holds, and
- (ii) for every $m\geq k, S(m)\to S(m+1)$,

then for every $n\geq k$, the statement $S(n)$ holds."

**Strong Induction**:
"Let $S(n)$ denote a statement regarding an integer $n$. If

- (i) $S(k)$ is true and
- (ii) for every $m\geq k, [S(k)\land S(k+1)\land\cdots\land S(m)]\to S(m+1)$,

then for every $n\geq k$, the statement $S(n)$ is true. "

---

Here is the proof offered for **Weak Induction Implies Strong Induction**:

> Assume that for some $k$, the statement $S(k)$ is true and for every $m\geq k, [S(k)\land S(k+1)\land\cdot\land S(m)]\to S(m+1)$. Let $B$ be the set of all $n>m$ for which $S(n)$ is false. If $B\neq\varnothing, B\subset\mathbb{N}$ and so by well-ordering, $B$ has a least element, say $\ell$. By the definition of $B$, for every $k\leq t<\ell, S(t)$ is true. The premise of the inductive hypothesis is true, and so $S(\ell)$ is true, contradicting that $\ell\in B$. Hence $B=\varnothing$. $\blacksquare$

---

Here is my conversion to a formal FOL expression (step by step).

The claim to prove:

$\forall k \Big ( \Big [ S(k) \land \forall m \geq k \big (S(m) \rightarrow S(m+1) \big) \Big] \rightarrow \Big[S(k) \land \forall m \geq k \big(S(k) \land S(k+1) \land ... \land S(m) \rightarrow S(m+1) \Big] \Big ) $

The author proceeds with a proof by contradiction which amounts to negating the previous statement and arriving at a contradiction. The negation of $P \rightarrow Q$ is $P \land \neg Q$. And the negation of $R \land S$ is $\neg R \lor \neg S$.  Using this, the negated statement is:

$\exists k \Big ( \Big [ S(k) \land \forall m \geq k \big (S(m) \rightarrow S(m+1) \big) \Big] \land\Big[\neg S(k) \lor \neg [\forall m \geq k \big(S(k) \land S(k+1) \land ... \land S(m) \rightarrow S(m+1)] \Big] \Big ) $

In order for this statement to be true, it is clear that $S(k)$ is true, which means that $\neg S(k)$ *cannot* also so be true. Therefore, in the disjunction, it must be the formula  $\neg [\forall m \geq k \big(S(k) \land S(k+1) \land ... \land S(m) \rightarrow S(m+1)]$ that is true.

This is equivalent to $\exists m \geq k \Big ( S(k) \land S(k+1) \land ... \land S (m) \land \neg S(m+1) \Big )$.

It seems like we could really just stop right here...because $\neg S(m+1)$ would contradict the fact that the weak induction hypothesis gives us $\forall n \geq k \  S(n)$. If someone could explain why the author continues with his set $B$ construction, I would greatly appreciate it. Even if we were to construct a set $B:=\{n \in \mathbb N| n \gt m\ \land \neg S(n)\}$, it is still the case that $\neg S(m+1)$ is a contradictory statement. The construction of $B$ seems unnecessary.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author was simply giving an ordinary mathematical proof. He didn’t **continue** with his set $B$ construction: he **started** with it. The FOL manipulations with which you started probably never even entered his mind; they certainly would not have entered mine, and they strike me as completely unnecessary. Given the equivalence between weak induction and well-ordering of $\Bbb N$, this ‘least counterexample’ approach is a standard, natural way to use induction.

One can, however, also prove the result directly from the statement of weak induction. Assume the hypothesis of strong induction. For $m\ge k$ let $P(m)$ be the statement $\bigwedge_{i=k}^mS(i)$. Then $P(k)=S(k)$ is true, and $P(m)\to P(m+1)$ for each $m\ge k$, so by weak induction $P(n)$ is true for each $n\ge k$, and therefore $S(n)$ is true for each $n\ge k$.

Comment: This is really surprising to me. I've only read 2 introductory books before reading Kenneth Kunen's The Foundations of Mathematics. From this book, my impression was that *all* of you seasoned mathsters were, behind the scenes (in your head), thinking of things in FOL. I guess I just don't even understand how you know how to proceed with a proof if the formal FOL structure is not guiding your actions. How do you know that what you are doing is even correct? (Sorry, hah, probably a difficult question to answer in 500 characters...thank you for your input as always)

Comment: @S.Cramer: The same way that people did centuries before the formalization that is FOL was invented; after all, FOL is just a formal version of ordinary reasoning. And I can guarantee that Ken, whom I know pretty well when I was in grad school, did *not* think in FOL. One reason that he was such a good teacher is that he was good at conveying the essential ideas — what was really going on, so to speak — something that formalization often tends to hide. It’s just that the subject of that book is one that requires more recourse to formalization than most just by its nature.

Comment: When you say that, "The FOL manipulations...are completely unnecessary" (I hear this often when I post personal proofs), what exactly do you *mean*? What does it mean for a proof to be *unnecessary*? "Redundancy" and "lack of organization", sure...those qualities are rightfully criticized. But I am not sure what is unnecessary about, for example, the proof I posted above. I have 4 total FOL sentences to tackle the claim. Daniel W. Farlow (the author of the Weak Induction Implies Strong Induction proof I am discussing) has 5 English sentences to tackle the claim. Why is his *less* unnecessary?

Comment: I hope this doesn't come off as being sassy or having an attitude (absolutely not my intent). I'm just trying to piece together how to improve my writing and thinking.

Comment: @S.Cramer: What I mean is that the excessive formalism is unnecessary. It makes the argument harder than necessary to read and follow and does so for no really good reason. The analogy is loose, but it’s a bit as if you were to insist on presenting algorithms in the machine language of some computer instead of in pseudocode.