# Equivalence of mathematical induction and strong induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, induction

In the book *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 8e, Kenneth Rosen* it is mentioned that:

> ... mathematical induction and strong induction are equivalent. That is,
> each can be shown to be a valid proof technique assuming that the
> other is valid.

I interpret this to mean that neither proof technique can be used where the other could not be used.  That being the case, why bother about strong induction at all?

Comment: for convenience

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is the difference between weak and strong induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184541/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-weak-and-strong-induction)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to prove F(n) is true, then it is more convenient to work with the fact that for all 1 <= k < n, F(k) is true, rather than just k = n-1 because you may need to depend on a sub-problem other than F(n-1).

For example, if we wanted to prove the Fibonacci recurrence T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) has some closed form g(n), then we could leverage strong induction for convenience.